# Rails3.1: Is this the right way to require my locally being developed gem/engine in the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, bundler, rails-engines

Still diving into the interesting (but a bit confusing) world of developing my own gem/engine.

I have successfully deployed it to my (private) GitHub account, but as the gem is in continuous development, I don't want to deploy it again and again and then do `bundle update`, etc., so I found the option to require a gem by specifying a path like this:

```
gem 'my_gem', path: 'path/to/my/gem'
```

This works nicely when developing (it even seems to reload changed files from the gem when `rails s` is running [at least for helpers and views it seems to do it, didn't use controllers and models yet, but hoping this will be the case for them, too], which is niiiice for developing the engine while using it straight away in the host Rails app).

But when deploying to the production server, I'd like to get the gem from github:

```
gem 'my_gem', git: "git@github.com:my_company/my_gem"
```

Sadly, bundler doesn't allow to have a gem required more than once (even when they are in separate `development/test` and `production` groups), so I'm doing the following:

```
if File.directory?('../my_gem')
  gem 'my_gem', path: '../my_gem'
else
  gem 'my_gem', git: "git@github.com:my_company/my_gem.git"
end
```

This seems to work nicely so far (didn't test deployment using Capistrano yet, though). But it leaves some questions:

1) Is this the "right" way to solve my problem? Seems a bit odd that I didn't find a much simpler way yet, something like:

```
gem 'my_gem', path: '../my_gem', git: "git@github.com:my_company/my_gem.git"
```

...where I'd expect bundler to simply try the `:path` option first, and if it's not available, it's try the `:git` option. But as far as I see, when doing this, it only uses the `:git` option.

2) Is it good practice to develop gems like this? I'm extracting some functionality from my host app into an engine, and at the same time, I'm enhancing this functionality. So I have the engine gem loaded within my host app, and from within my host app I change the engine's codes which are (thank God!) reflected within my host app without having to restart the rails server. This feels quite "right", but as there is a dummy Rails app within the created engine, I'm a bit unsure whether I rather should develop my engine's strictly isolated from my host app, or not. I think this is a bit of a philosophical question, but maybe someone has an opinion about it and can post pros and contras?

3) How do I tell Capistrano to always update my own gem to the newest version from GitHub automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] != "development"
  gem 'my_gem', git: "git@github.com:my_company/my_gem.git"
else
  gem 'my_gem', path: '../my_gem'
end
```

assuming that `RAILS_ENV` is being passed into the `bundle` command (which is so when using capistrano).

To update your gem to the latest, try making a capistrano task that essentially does this

```
/path/to/bundler update my_gem
```

I can't really comment on your other points. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thank you, this is useful information. I'll wait for some more answers though. :)

Comment: And wouldn't it be better to use `if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "production"`? Because in test env I want to use the dev gem, too.

Comment: I think `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` might not be passed in for test environment. But I did `!= "development"` just in case you had a staging environment.